# serializing a List<knowntype> to a specific xml format

Tags: c#, xml

I have this list property in a class and I need to decorate it with the correct xml attributes to get it in the form:

```
<Attachments>
    <Documents>
        <Document>
            the DocumentType nodes...
        </Document>
        <Document>
            the DocumentType nodes...
        </Document>
    </Documents>
</Attachments>
```

when I serialize the object. Here is the declaration of the list property within the class:

```
[XmlArrayItem("Documents", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlArrayItem("Document", IsNullable = false, NestingLevel = 1)]
public List<DocumentType> Attachments
{
    get
    {
        return this._attachments;
    }
    set
    {
        this._attachments = value;
    }
}
```

Currently what I get is this:

```
<Attachments>
    <Documents>
        the DocumentType nodes...
    </Documents>
    <Documents>
        the DocumentType nodes...
    </Documents>
</Attachments>
```

Its clear to me that the "Documents" node I want should be declared something other than an XmlArrayItemAttribute. The name of the list can not change. Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: Try changing to  `[XmlArray("Documents")] [XmlArrayItem("Document")]`

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how the 'DocumentType' looks like but can define it as follow:

```
public class DocumentType
    {
        [XmlElement("Document")]
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }


public class Test
{
    private List<DocumentType> _attachments = new List<DocumentType>();

    [XmlArrayItem("Documents", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<DocumentType> Attachments
    {
        get
        {
            return this._attachments;
        }
        set
        {
            this._attachments = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The Xml after serialization:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Attachments>
    <Documents>
      <Document>A Node</Document>
      <Document>B Node</Document>
    </Documents>
  </Attachments>
</Test
```